# Application tags in OpenSSL ASN.1 template engine?

Tags: c, openssl, asn.1

I'm trying to use OpenSSL ASN.1 template API (from asn1t.h) to parse ASN.1 objects in my application.
The thing is that I have to use application tags instead of default ones:

```
Foo ::= [APPLICATION 13] SEQUENCE {
m01 INTEGER,
m02 OCTET STRING
}
```

and the macros (like ASN1_SEQUENCE) don't seem to provide app tags params.

Comment: Manual tagging is seen (these days) as being old fashioned; automatic tagging is the thing (though I have found modern uses for manual tagging). I'm not quite sure what you're actually trying to accomplish; you may find this open source C asn.1 compiler useful: https://github.com/ttsiodras/asn1scc

Comment: Er, I actually meant to point to this one: https://github.com/vlm/asn1c